# Angular routerlink shows %20 before id path?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, routerlink

I am looking to display messages from a nested messages collection.
I have some cards and when i click on view a tag i use routerlink to go to the desired path to see the messages.
One out of 3 cards has a correct cardiD [![enter image description here][1]][1]link and displays the messages correty, but the other 2 cards get a %20 in front os cardId link on search bar. The result is that i display cards correct fields but messages can't be displayed.

Comment: %20 is the encoding for whitespace. make sure your links are correct

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @DarrenLamb It was a whitespace in the database id field for these 2 specific card. Now i will remember that whitespace error. Thanks a lot

Comment: @DarrenLamb it's the URL encoded " " space character, not so much white space. There are a few different whitespace charaters, such as tab too.

Comment: @DarrenLamb Could you post your comment as an answer? That will be of help for the community members that have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`%20` is the URL encoding for whitespace, or as Austin T French more accurately pointed out it is specifically the encoding for the " " character.

There are a bunch of other % encoded characters that you might come across and you can [easily find a list of them online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

In this instance you probably just need to make sure you trim your links of any whitespace.